# How to find GXT Grid scroll response time

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, gxt

I have a GXT Grid with 1000 of records, while scroll the grid once the data is loaded it is talking too much of time for each scrolling. When i click on scroll up/down to load next record it struck for a while and loads the record in IE but same issue is not there with FF. Is there any IE plugin or add-on that helps in measuring the time of each click IE?

Answer (score 0):

ou are loading 1000 at a time .So its taking much time to create the DOM .If you are scrolling while creating DOM a weard behaviour will form and browser goes not responding mode ..

So use `AJAX` and reduce the pain of DOM .load few records on first shot and put a more button .Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, As you said it's correct, my question is there any IE plug-in which helps me in calculate the time for each hit.